# How to deserialize json object into class

Tags: c#, json, json.net, json-deserialization

I have the following json string:

```
    private const string Json = @"{
        'responseMessage': '',
        'response': 'PASS',
        'responseData': {
            'user': {
            'initials': 'XXX',
            'name': 'XXXX XXXX',
            'companies': [
                '0002',
                '0007',
                '0022',
                '0033',
                '9999'
            ],
            'employee': 'XXXX'
            }
        },
        'responseFor': 'myCommand'
    }'";
```

My ServerResponse class looks like this:

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ServerResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("responseFor")]
    public string ResponseFor { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responseData")]
    public string ResponseData { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("response")]
    public string Response { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("responseMessage")]
    public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}
```

I call this command:

```
var serverResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServerResponse>(Json);
```

I would expect that this would fill in my serverResponse object but instead I get this exception:

```
{Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException: Error reading string. Unexpected token: StartObject. Path 'responseData', line 4, position 30.
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader.ReadAsStringInternal () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.JsonTextReader.ReadAsString () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.ReadForType (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonContract contract, Boolean hasConverter) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 
  at Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonSerializerInternalReader.PopulateObject (System.Object newObject, Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReader reader, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonObjectContract contract, Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.JsonProperty member, System.String id) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0 }
```

What am I doing wrong here??

Comment: `responseData` is not a string, it's an object with several fields.

Comment: What would I define ResponseData as in my ServerResponse class?  I already tried List<string> ResponseData.

Comment: It's not a list of strings. It's an object. With fields. As I stated.

Comment: I am presently doing something like this:  var jsonServerResponse = JObject.Parse(response); which works it just feels ugly because I need to do things like var responseData = JObject.Parse(jsonServerResponse["responseData"].ToString());

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a class for ResponseData in order for the serialization to work, as the value for it in your json is not a string. You'll also need one for User.

Create response data and user classes that looks something like this.

```
[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class User
{
     [JsonProperty("initials")]
     public string Initials { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("name")]
     public string Name { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("companies")]
     public string[] Companies { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("responseMessage")]
     public string ResponseMessage { get; set; }
}

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
public class ResponseData
{
     [JsonProperty("user")]
     public User User { get; set; }

     [JsonProperty("employee")]
     public string Employee { get; set; }
}
```

Then in your ServerResponse class, change ResponseData to use this ResponseData class.